# Application Client Agent Design

Tags: windows-services, system-tray, agent

I need to create a small app which will run on my client machines as "agent" which will periodically check in with a server for certain tasks.

Do I

1. Create the app as a windows service with an interface for configurations?
2. Create an app which will run in system tray, with an interface for configuration?

Many moons ago I read that windows service app should not have any configuration interface. I would assume that even if I do create a windows service, there will have to be a second app which interacts with the service as the interface for configuration, correct?

Comment: One advantage of a service over a system tray app is that the service can run even without a user logged onto the machine.

Answer (score 0):

If the application needs to be started and configured by a user without administrator rights, then you would need to go with the system tray approach because a service can only be started by an administrator.  Otherwise either approach would work.  The best approach would depend on the application.